# display icon before content css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to show some help text and info icon on the left hand side of the div (bootstrap 3). I have managed to display the icon by using the before class  but the problem is it is not dynamic and also the icon is always shoved up on top. I do not want to hard code the margins or height for the div on the left as I do not know how long the display text will be.

```
.crmEntityFormView div.description.above:before {
content: "";
display: block;
background: url("info-icon.png") no-repeat;
background-color:#f7f7f7;
background-position: center;
width: 35px;
height:55px;
float: left;
margin: 10px 6px 0 0;
}
```

output is like this but I want the grey column on the left to expand vertically to the same height of the description text and icon to be vertically aligned in middle.  : [image]

Answer (score 0):

You could make the containing div a flexbox and set the `:before` to have `align-self: center;`